# Looping over list of states and appending before exporting to a csv in R

Tags: r, api, loops, append, census

I'm looking to use the getCensus command to grab information from a series ID for all tracts in every state in the US. The Census API doesn't let you do this automatically (only lets you get all tracts from one state at a time), so I am looking for a way to loop through every state to gather all tracts, append each result, and then export to one large csv.

I currently have code that exports each state's result to a csv:

```
library(censusapi)

list<- listCensusMetadata("acs/acs5/profile", vintage=2017, group="DP04", type="variables")

tract5yrunits1<- getCensus(name = "acs/acs5/profile", 
                          vintage=2017, 
                          vars=c("NAME", "DP04_0011E", "DP04_0012E","DP04_0013E"),
                          region = "tract:*",
                          regionin = "state:01")
View(tract5yrunits1)
write.csv(tract5yrunits1,'tract5yrunits1.csv')
```

Where 1 is the first state (AK). But I would like to loop through a vector of states, append, and export the appended file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
tract5yrunits<- getCensus(name = "acs/acs5/profile", 
                          vintage=2017, 
                          vars=c("NAME", "DP04_0011E", "DP04_0012E","DP04_0013E"),
                          region = "tract:*",
                          regionin = "state:01")
# states vector
states <- as.character(seq(2,50))
states[1:8] <- paste("0",states[1:8],sep="")
# loop through states
for (state in states) {
    tract5yrunitstemp<- getCensus(name = "acs/acs5/profile", 
                          vintage=2017, 
                          vars=c("NAME", "DP04_0011E", "DP04_0012E","DP04_0013E"),
                          region = "tract:*",
                          regionin = paste("state:",state,sep=""))
    # add rows
    tract5yrunits <- rbind(tract5yrunits,tract5yrunitstemp)
}
write.csv(tract5yrunits1,'tract5yrunits1.csv')
```

Comment: I'm now getting errors regarding the commas such as after vintage=2017,    and the end ) after sep=""), thus tract5yrunitstemp is not found.

Comment: That's because I wrote the laziest for loop ever and messed up the syntax. Edited the answer to fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great.